# Radio buttons in a gridview

Tags: html, css, jsp

In this table, when I check the radio button (present) on the 1st row and when I go and check again the present on the 2nd row, the first row present in getting unchecked automatically. And all the radiobutton gets checked. This is just a sample for two students.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>


<head>
<title>HTML Tables</title>
</head>
<body>

<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

<table bgcolor="lightgray" border="5" width="60%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0.5" color="blue" >
<tr>

<th colspan ="3" bgcolor="#999999"><br>


<div align="Center" > <font face="verdana" size="5" color="white"> ATTENDANCE </font> 
</div>
</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="14%"><h3>Register No</td>
<td><h3> Student Name</td>
<td><h3> Attendance</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> 1 </td>
<td> <input type="radio" >Present <input type="radio">Absent
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td> <input type="radio" >Present <input type="radio">Absent
</tr>



<% 
Connection dbcon=null;
   
 DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
  dbcon=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","scott","tiger");
  Statement stmt=dbcon.createStatement();
  ResultSet rst=null;
  
rst=stmt.executeQuery("select * from studenttables");
while(rst.next())
{%> 
<tr>

<td><%=rst.getString("name")%></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><%=rst.getString("name")%></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><%=1%></td>
<td><%=rst.getString("name")%></td>
<td><input type="radio" >Present <input type="radio">Absent
</tr>
  
<% } %> 


</table>
</body>
</html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: radiobutton gridview image]

Comment: Radio buttons need to share a name where they form a mutually exclusive group. Presently you have not named them at all, so they are effectively all in the group with no name. Try naming each pair thus: `<input type="radio" name="student_1" value="present">` and then using a value attribute to differentiate between the two different cases.

Answer (score 2):

Set a name and make a group of radio buttons like

```
() - name="rdg1" and id="Present"
() - name="rdg1" and id="Absent"
```

and

```
() - name="rdg2" and id="Present2"
() - name="rdg2" and id="Absent2"
```

if the rdg1 - Present is checked and you click to check the rdg1 - Absent the check box 1 will clear, same to second group.

Comment: I'd say that the radio buttons might not need `id` attributes anyway - I think `name` is enough.